# Read the sender of the mail received in outlook

Tags: vbscript, outlook, server, copy

I want to read the sender of the mail received in outlook and if the sender matches a partcular sender.A copy process should be happened from one remote server to another remote server ? can anyone help me ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to/can't just implement a Mail Rule in Outlook for the sender and select to run a script that does the file copy?  What have you tried already?

Comment: It is giving run time error "440"  can not parse the condition at MailPropertyValue= "xyz@abc.com"

Comment: That makes no sense as it's just a string value - post your code?

Answer (score 1):

VB Script code:

```
Set objOutlook= CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutlookSetNameSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set OutlookSetFolder = OutlookSetNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(6) ' 6 for Inbox folder
Set objAllMails= OutlookSetFolder.Items
MailProperty="From"
MailPropertyValue= "xyz@abc.com"
Set ObjFilteredMails=objAllMails.Restrict("[" & MailProperty & "] = " & MailPropertyValue)
UreadCount=ObjFilteredMails.Count
if UreadCount>0 then
 '---write your copy script here
End if
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but It is giving run time error "440" can not parse the condition.... could you please help me in this

Answer (score 1):

Corrected version of Kiran's answer:

```
Set objOutlook= CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutlookSetNameSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set OutlookSetFolder = OutlookSetNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(6) ' 6 for Inbox folder
Set objAllMails= OutlookSetFolder.Items
MailProperty="From"
MailPropertyValue= "xyz@abc.com"
Set ObjFilteredMails=objAllMails.Restrict("[" & MailProperty & "] = '" & MailPropertyValue & "'")  ' needs quoted
UreadCount=ObjFilteredMails.Count
if UreadCount>0 then
 '---write your copy script here
End if
```

Comment: Still I am not able to fetch the mail id (sender mail ID) with a particular sender from the inbox of the outlook........

Comment: What error are you getting?  Please be specific with what's happening as "it doesn't work" doesn't give anyone much to work with

Comment: It is not providing any desired result. It is not giving any error too

Comment: Just tried it locally - the filter on From relies on you providing the name of the email sender rather than their address (or rather whatever value is actually in the From field), not the email address of the sender...

Comment: In outlook it is showing the mail id in the from column and not the name of the sender !!